# Difference between using "chmod a+x" and "chmod 755"

Tags: linux, unix, chmod

This may sound silly, but I have a file/ script that need to run and in order to do it I must change it to become executable. I would want to use either `chmod a+x` or `chmod 755`. But is there a difference between using `chmod a+x` and `chmod 755`?

Comment: chmod is short for change mode. 
chmod [references][operator][modes] file
a+x meaning is 
a -> all(owner,group and other)

Answer (score 103, accepted):

`chmod a+x` *modifies* the argument's mode while `chmod 755` *sets* it. Try both variants on something that has full or no permissions and you will notice the difference.

Comment: One modifies and one sets. Well explained!

Comment: ls -llh tempfile --> -rwerwerwe  ............. chmod 755 tempfile --> -rwer-er-e .......... But chmod a+x tempfile --> -rwerwerwe

Comment: In other words, `chmod a+x` reads the permissions, and then writes, whereas `chmod 755` only writes.

Answer (score 84):

Yes - different

`chmod a+x` will add the exec bits to the file but will not touch other bits. For example file might be still unreadable to `others` and `group`.

`chmod 755` will always make the file with perms `755` no matter what initial permissions were.

This may or may not matter for your script.

Comment: This supposed to be the accepted answer

Answer (score 47):

Indeed there is.

`chmod a+x` is relative to the current state and just sets the `x` flag. So a 640 file becomes 751 (or 750?), a 644 file becomes 755.

`chmod 755`, however, sets the mask as written: `rwxr-xr-x`, no matter how it was before. It is equivalent to `chmod u=rwx,go=rx`.